# how to create a multi-line label dynamically in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

The scenario is i want to populate the label data dynamically based o the size of the string.say if the string length is 100 ,first 30 characters must be populated in first label,the remaining 30 on next label and so on.

what i have done so far

```
Dim remcontent, remcontentlength, remcontentlabelcount, labelcounter As New Integer
                Dim rc As Integer = 30
                Dim remcontentstring As String
                remcontentlength = row.Item(4).ToString.Length
                Dim endindex As Integer = 30
                Dim startindex As Integer = 0


                If remcontentlength > 30 Then
                    Dim actualremcontent As String
                    actualremcontent = "Note :" + row.Item(4).ToString

                    Dim modcheck As Integer
                    modcheck = remcontentlength Mod 30
                    If modcheck = 0 Then
                        remcontentlabelcount = (remcontentlength / 30)
                    Else
                        remcontentlabelcount = (Math.Floor(remcontentlength \ 30)) + 1
                    End If
                   ReDim remindercontantmulti(remcontentlabelcount)
                    For labelcounter = 1 To remcontentlabelcount
                        remindercontantmulti(labelcounter) = New Label
                        With remindercontantmulti(labelcounter)
                            .Name = "remindercontant " + x.ToString + labelcounter.ToString
                            .Text = actualremcontent.ToString.Substring(startindex, endindex)
                            .Visible = True
                            .Top = (22 * (x + (aa + 1))) + 10
                            .AutoSize = True
                            '.Left = reminderTime(x).Left + reminderTime(x).Width + 20
                            .BackColor = Color.Transparent
                            '.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
                            .TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight
                            .Font = New Drawing.Font("Trebuchet MS", 8, FontStyle.Regular)
                            Me.Panel4.Controls.Add(remindercontantmulti(labelcounter))
                            aa = aa + 1
                        End With
                        If Not startindex = 0 Then
                            startindex = startindex + rc
                            If (rc * labelcounter) < remcontentlength Then
                                endindex = remcontentlength - startindex
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next labelcounter
                    Else
                    remindercontant(x) = New Label
                    With remindercontant(x)
                        .Name = "remindercontant " + x.ToString
                        .Text = "Note :" + row.Item(4).ToString
                        .Visible = True
                        .Top = (22 * (x + (aa + 1))) + 10
                        .AutoSize = True
                        '.Left = reminderTime(x).Left + reminderTime(x).Width + 20
                        .BackColor = Color.Transparent
                        '.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
                        .TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight
                        .Font = New Drawing.Font("Trebuchet MS", 8, FontStyle.Regular)
                        Me.Panel4.Controls.Add(remindercontant(x))
                        aa = aa + 1
                    End With
                End If
```

Comment: What is the problem that you are having?

Comment: First get a working function that will print 30 characters to a label. The other stuff is then made trivial.

Comment: this code prints only first 30 characters on all the labels(repeatedly).i want the other remaining characters to be populated on other labels rather than repeating  the same 30 characters on all labels

Comment: Based on what you said, without testing it myself, I'd say that the problem resides in the line that says `If Not startindex = 0 Then`.  The `startindex` variable is initialized to 0, and unless I'm missing something, it's only inside that `If` block where the value of the `startindex` variable is incremented.  Therefore, it would always stay at 0.